# Can't get a Slack bot token (xoxb)

Tags: slack-api

I've spent a couple of hours on that, and I think I'm going to become crazy!

I already did this kind of setup a year ago, but now, it's not working anymore. I'm just trying to get a **xoxb** token to use from my personal Slack bot on my personal workspace.

It should be easy, but I can't get it working. Each time I install the app, I have the notif on the Slack channel, but on the management side I don't have anything at all. Usually the button changes from **Install** to **Reinstall**, but mine stays stuck in **Install**.

If I add a OAuth permission under **User Token Scopes**, I can install the app but I only get a **xoxp** token. And even with my permissions under **Bot Token Scopes**, I don't have any **xoxb** token.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but still:

1. You have to click `Install App to Workspace`. 
   For me it only created `User OAuth Token`.
2. To get `Bot User OAuth Token`
   I clicked `Reinstall to Workspace` and only then it appears.

See also:

- https://api.slack.com/apps 
  (Generate App / Bot token)
- https://api.slack.com/start/quickstart 
  (Slack's Guide for adding permissions)